# Enlive: append a snippet in a template without parent element?

Tags: clojure, enlive

Say I have only access to `<article>` and child elements in my `/public/articles.html` file.

```
   ...
   <article class="clj-article">
        <h1 class="clj-title"></h1>
        <p class="clj-date"></p>
        <ul>
            <li class="clj-tag"></li>
        </ul>
    </article>
    ...
```

How can I iterate on `<article>` without knowing about a parent element? (with a `defsnippet` in a `deftemplate`)

```
(def articles [{:title "title1"
                :date "date1"
                :tags ["tag1" "other tag1"]}
               {:title "title2"
                :date "date2"
                :tags ["tag2" "other tag2"]}])

(e/defsnippet show-articles "public/articles.html" [:.clj-article] [articles]
  [:.clj-article]
    (e/clone-for [a articles]
      [:.clj-title]
        (e/content (:title a))
      [:.clj-date]
        (e/content (:date a))
      [:.clj-tag]
        (e/clone-for [t (:tags a)]
          [:.clj-tag] (e/content t))))
```

My snippet give the output I need, and then I want to insert it in my template (as well as other snippets in other parts of articles.html) As I don't know about `.clj-article` parent element, I've tried targeting it:

```
(e/deftemplate index "public/articles.html" []
  [:.clj-article]
       (e/append (show-articles articles)))
```

I get the output I wish, but wrapped in an other `<article>` and children pattern.

```
<article class="clj-article">
    <h1 class="clj-title"></h1>
    <p class="clj-date"></p>
    <ul class="clj-tags">
        <li class="clj-tag"></li>
    </ul>
    <article class="clj-article">
        <h1 class="clj-title">title1</h1>
        <p class="clj-date">date1</p>
        <ul class="clj-tags">
            <li class="clj-tag">tag1</li>
            <li class="clj-tag">other tag1</li>
        </ul>
    </article>
    <article class="clj-article">  <h1 class="clj-title">title2</h1>
        <p class="clj-date">date2</p>
        <ul class="clj-tags">
            <li class="clj-tag">tag2</li>
            <li class="clj-tag">other tag2</li>
        </ul>
    </article>
</article>
```

How can I prevent that from happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Christophe Grand had the answer in his wonderful tutorial! 
https://github.com/cgrand/enlive/wiki/Table-and-Layout-Tutorial,-Part-3:-Simple-Transformations#whole-tag-transformations

Instead of appending ou prepending a snippet to a parent element, overwrite the actual element by using `e/substitute`

```
(e/deftemplate index "public/articles.html" []
  [:.clj-article]
       (e/substitute (show-articles articles)))
```